# Does $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$ imply that $f(x) = 1$ when $x = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, definition

If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$, then is it correct to state it as $f(x) = 1$ when $x = \infty$?

Can we define a function in this way, if not why? Also if a limit exists at a point $x$ then does the function always has to be defined for that  $x$ with the same value obtained through the limit?

Comment: I am no expert, but you use the limit, because you can't say in elementary calculus, that $x = \infty$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac xx=1$, but $\dfrac xx$ is not defined when $x=0$

Comment: $\infty\notin \mathbb  R$

Answer (score 5):

Remember, a limit is what happens '*as you approach something*' not '*once you get there*'. Meaning, the function does not even have to be defined there. For example, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} x^2= 0$ and if $f(x)=x^2$, we have $f(0)=0$. But for $f(x)= \frac{\sin x}{x}$, we have
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}= 1
$$
But $f(0)$ is not defined.

Now you undoubtably have seen if a function is failed to be defined at a value but the limit exists there, we have a removable discontinuity that we can 'fill in' by defining it there. So we can define
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin x}{x}, & x \neq 0 \\
1, & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
Now $g(x)$ is continuous. This seems to be what you're thinking about in your question. However, you are working with limits over the real numbers so $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but $\pm \infty \notin \mathbb{R}$. So it makes no sense for you to define a function at $\pm \infty$, instead merely to talk about what happens to a function $f(x)$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Can we define $
g(x)= 2$, at $x=0
$, I mean surely to make $g(x)$ continuous at x=0 we need to have $g(0)=1$ but do we have the liberty to define $g(0)$ to have a value other than 1?

Comment: @Hanzel Of course, you can define $g$ to have any value you would like at $x=0$ (or have it not be defined there at all). Obviously, the only choice which makes $g$ continuous is $g(0)=1$.

Answer (score 3):

If, say, $f$ is a function from $(0,\infty)$ to $\Bbb R$ and if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, then, no you cannot say that $f(\infty)=1$ because $f(x)$ is undefined if $x=\infty$; $f(x)$ is defined only when $x\in(0,\infty)$.

And if $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is defined by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ if }x=0,\end{cases}$$then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=1$, but $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The notation $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 1$ has a very precise meaning.  It means that given any $\varepsilon>0$ we can always find a real number $c$ such that for all $x > c$ we have $|f(x) - 1| < \varepsilon.$  Note that nowhere in there do we know what the *exact* value of $f(x)$ is at a particular point $x$.

Beyond that, $\infty$ is not a number, so it doesn't make sense in this context to define $f(\infty)$ or say $x = \infty$.

To answer your last question, no, we don't require functions to be defined so that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$.  This means that the function is *continuous* at $x = a$, which is not true of all functions.

Comment: Sorry but your claims are completely incorrect. In the affinely-extended reals, it makes complete sense to extend $f$ to $f^*$ by defining $f^*(x) = f(x)$ for every real $x$ and also $f^*(∞) = \lim_{x→∞} f(x)$ since the limit is given to exist. The topological definition of limits works fine, and we can easily prove that $f^*$ is continuous at $∞$. Your so-called "precise meaning" of a limit is a much less definition which is why it fails to extend correctly.